# How do I winterize this sprinkler system

Tags: plumbing, sprinkler-system, winterizing

I am trying winterize my landscaping sprinklers.  I just moved into my new house and find out this plumbing layout is quite different, I hooked up my 100psi air compressor and tried to blow them out but no luck. I can't get a hold of the old owners so I don't know what to do right now, but snow is coming soon here in Utah.

Update #1: Looks like there is no backflow prevention device.

Thanks a lot!

[image: sprinkler1]

[image: sprinkler2]

Comment: When you tried blowing them out did you remember to manually open the solenoid valves and close the relief valve in the manifold box?

Comment: I have opened the solenoids for the sprinklers buy can't find the relief valve in the manifold.

Comment: By the way, it's a PGV valve by Hunter.

Comment: I believe the ball valve in the manifold is the relief one, so yes it's close right now.

Comment: I give up on this, I believe there is a broken pipe somewhere, thanks for your help anyways. Feel free to close this question.

Comment: @AngelEscobedo I could be wrong, but it seems like it would be valuable to the community to post the solution when you figure it out.  Even if it's a broken pipe, just knowing that that's what the problem was for sure might help the next guy.  Or gal :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to hookup an air compressor at all, should have contacted the local city water department first. They told me that the secondary water supplier will shutoff the valves on their end and this will cause the water to drain back leaving very small amounts of water in the pipes to be blown if you really wanted to use an air compressor.